# Credential Without Asking For Prompts In Powershell

Tags: powershell

My current script prompts for user credentials in order to remote sign into exchange server.
Is their a way to provide credentials in script and automatically sign into exchange server without prompt?

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXdomain.local/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential

Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
```

Comment: Can it be done? Yes, but you would have to leave your password in plain text saved in the script (or read in by the script). It is **not recommended** to do that!

Comment: In an interactive session (ie. you launch powershell from your desktop session), or an unattended session (scheduled task for example)?